how to handle redirect uri from keycloak server properly
I need to make a login page with OpenId provider. I copied the code from the expo tutorial page for Keycloak server and saw that the user can log in. However, I don't understand why every time the login is successful on the Android app, it is redirected to a different page and reports unmatched route myapp:///oauth2redirect (my original page is index.tsx).
I configured the redirect uri on the server as myapp:/oauth2redirect. I think if the server has returned the authentication code, then I must have configured the server correctly. Now I just don't know what to do because on Android it keeps redirecting to another route while I want to receive the result and continue the authentication flow on the same original route.
Here's my source code:
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest, useAutoDiscovery } from 'expo-auth-session';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function LoginScreen() {
  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(<my-server-address>);
  const url = Linking.useURL()

  /*if (url) {
    console.log(Linking.parse(url));
  } else {
    console.log("no deeplinking");    
  }*/
  const redirectUri =  makeRedirectUri({
    scheme: 'myapp',
    path: 'oauth2redirect' 
  });
  console.log(redirectUri);
  
  // Create and load an auth request
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'my-client-id',
      redirectUri,
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile']
    },
    discovery
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    WebBrowser.warmUpAsync()
    return () => { WebBrowser.coolDownAsync(); };
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }, [response])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="LOGIN" 
              disabled={!request} 
              onPress={() => promptAsync()} />
      {response && <Text>{JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}


I have tried to add the linking listener for the url, create a new tsx file with the same name as the redirect uri.
I expect that I can read the response and proceed with the authentication flow from the same original tsx file (index.tsx).

Might be a type in the description, but make sure that you have the right amount of forward slashes in your uri.

@user18309290 : I also feel like I have made mistake with the amount of slashes, but I don't know where. Therefore, what I put in the description is exactly what I have configured the server and implemented on React Native. May you share your view on where I can be wrong?

Take a look at this: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#redirect-uri-patterns

I have checked the document and updated the makeRedirectUri in index.tsx file accordingly to native one. It doesn't work. Then I changed back to use scheme and path and now I configure the redirect uri on keycloak server to myapp://oauth2redirect. It doesn't work either. The application tries to location myapp:///oauth2redirect (but it can't find) after user logins successfully. Then I tried to configure the redirect uri on server to myapp:///oauth2redirect and use the correct format in tsx file. The server can't handle the login request. Do you have any hint?

Just now, I tried to add listener for 'url' using Linkding from expo-linking. Interestingly, the amount of slashes returns from the server is 2. Here's the log: Deep link data: {"hostname": "oauth2redirect", "path": null, "queryParams": {"code": ....
However, if we look at the unmatched route page, it's trying to look for myapp:///oauth2redirect
When I add oauth2redirect to handle the route then it's invoked. However, it's not my expected behavior, I want the flow to route back to index.tsx.

Continue the trick with addListener for 'url' using Linking. I do a trick by getting the authentication code from url.data.queryParams?.code
It's working and I can continue with rest of the flow. Just I feel like, since I'm new to React Native, I have done sth urgly and not follow the common practice. Do you have any suggestion?
